# Shell script to install Elasticsearch throws error when install X-Pack with 'yes'

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm working on a shell script which automatically installs the latest Elasticsearch 5.0.0 GA version and the X-Pack plugin.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ========= ES INSTALL =========
wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-5.x.list
apt-get update && apt-get install -y elasticsearch

# ===== ES PLUGINS INSTALL =====
yes | ./usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
```

On X-Pack installation I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/x-pack
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:88)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.installBin(InstallPluginCommand.java:519)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.install(InstallPluginCommand.java:482)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:207)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:190)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:69)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:42)
```

If I call the X-Pack installation command without `yes |` then everything is ok.
What is the problem with the `yes |` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to 'echo' your 'yes'

```
echo "y" | sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
```